# Rome Colosseum queues in March

Tags: italy, rome

I plan to attend Colosseum next Sunday. How big queues shall we expect? We have ben there in august 2013 and the queue was at least 30 minutes long.

Similar question:
[How busy is the Roman Colosseum throughout the year?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71844/when-is-the-roman-colosseum-least-busy)

Comment: The linked question is a bit more broad as it covers the whole year. One of the answers also includes a convenient popularity chart by month.

Comment: I know. And can anobody tell me situation for March?

Comment: @JonathanReez are you kidding with this close as duplicate? I have linked that question and THERE IS NO ANSWER! That is why I have asked new question.

Comment: Yes, but the question there is basically the same, except that it covers the whole year. I will put a bounty there now.